# c++ unordered_multimap insert hash

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm going crazy over here. I have search google to find 1 single decent example where people use a unordered_map together with enum class and a hash function without any luck. Those i manage to find always end up saying "use map instead".

I'm trying to do the following:

**`Enum class facing`** is the direction my sprite is looking at.

**`Enum class Action`** is the action my sprite is doing.

**`Animation`** is a class that holds different animations which i will call later.

The container should look like this:

map

There can be more than 1 FACING in the map as key and there can be more than one ACTION in the pair.

Example:

```
map<LEFT, pair<ATTACK, attackAnimation>
map<LEFT, pair<IDLE, idleAnimation>
map<LEFTUP, pair<IDLE, idleAnimation>
```

This is an simplified everything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct Hash
{
    typedef typename std::underlying_type<T>::type underlyingType;
    typedef typename std::hash<underlyingType>::result_type resultType;
    resultType operator()(const T& arg) const
    {
        std::hash<underlyingType> hasher;
        return hasher(static_cast<underlyingType>(arg));
    }
};

class Animation
{
private:
    std::string str;

public:
    Animation(std::string _string)
    {
        this->str = _string;
    }

    std::string& GetString()
    {
        return this->str;
    }
};

class Bullshit
{
public:
    enum class Action
    {
        Attack,
        Move
    };

    enum class Facing
    {
        Right,
        Up,
        Left
    };

    Bullshit()
    {

    }

    std::unordered_multimap<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, std::unique_ptr<Animation>>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>>& GetlistAnimation()
    {
        return this->listAnimation;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_multimap<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, std::unique_ptr<Animation>>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>> listAnimation;
};


int main()
{
    Bullshit bull;
    auto myList = bull.GetlistAnimation();

    std::unique_ptr<Animation> anim(new Animation("test"));
    myList.insert(std::make_pair(Bullshit::Facing::Up, std::make_pair(Bullshit::Action::Attack, std::move(anim))));

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Error code:

> ```
> error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
> 1>          with
> 1>          [
> 1>              _Ty=Animation
> 1>          ]
> 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(1447) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr'
> 1>          with
> 1>          [
> 1>              _Ty=Animation
> 1>          ]
> 1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)'
> 1>          with
> 1>          [
> 1>              _Ty1=Bullshit::Action,
> 1>              _Ty2=std::unique_ptr<Animation>
> 1>          ]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
auto myList = bull.GetlistAnimation();
```

the type deduced for `myList` is `std::unordered_map<.....>`, that is, it's not a reference. And the copy can't be created because the map contains `unique_ptr`s. What you meant is

```
auto& myList = bull.GetlistAnimation();
```

or in C++14,

```
decltype(auto) myList = bull.GetlistAnimation();
```

Comment: @nilo Don't worry, there are whole [talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU) of experts about this mess.

Comment: I wonder if the OP really wants that, though. Returning a reference to a private member practically makes the member public.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with `unordered_map` or hash functions. It's the `std::unique_ptr`, which is uncopyable, and your `GetlistAnimation` attempts to copy it (indirectly).

How to **correctly** fix this depends on what you want to achieve.

A **quick fix** would be to use `std::shared_ptr` instead:

```
    std::unordered_map<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, std::shared_ptr<Animation>>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>>& GetlistAnimation()
    {
        return this->listAnimation;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, std::shared_ptr<Animation>>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>> listAnimation;
```

[...]

```
std::shared_ptr<Animation> anim(new Animation("test"));
myList.insert(std::make_pair(Bullshit::Facing::Up, std::make_pair(Bullshit::Action::Attack, anim)));
```

(By the way, you should use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).)

---

A fix which may be quick *and* correct (again, depending on what you want to achieve) is to get rid of the pointer logic altogether and just use `Animation` directly:

```
    std::unordered_map<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, Animation>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>>& GetlistAnimation()
    {
        return this->listAnimation;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Bullshit::Facing, std::pair<Bullshit::Action, Animation>,Hash<Bullshit::Facing>> listAnimation;
```

[...]

```
Animation anim("test");
myList.insert(std::make_pair(Bullshit::Facing::Up, std::make_pair(Bullshit::Action::Attack, anim)));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer me mate. Ill note it but the problem in my code was a freaking & after the auto which screwed everything up because i was so stressed.