# Error: static_assert failed "This hash only works for enumeration types" for unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-multimap

I'm trying to insert into an

```
    unordered_multimap<pair<int, int>, int>
```

like so:

```
    unordered_multimap<pair<int, int>, int> tree;

    auto firstPair=make_pair(firstNumber, secondNumber);

    tree.insert(make_pair(firstPair, 0));
```

However, the compiler proceeds to greet me with the following error upon compilation:

```
      error: static_assert failed "This hash only works for enumeration types"
```

Now, after some Google-fu and reading other questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121497/this-hash-only-works-for-enumeration-types) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207633/c-unordered-multimap-insert-hash)) here regarding this error, only with unordered_map instead, I've come to the conclusion that I need to provide my own hash function. However, this is confusing to me since the other questions I've read seem to involve keys that were custom (user-defined) classes and I don't consider a the type of key I'm using to be "custom." If anyone could provide insight on this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL doesn't define a hash function for `std::pair`. So you need to do the same thing as you would do if `std::pair<int, int>` was a type you created. You should declare your own implementation of `std::hash`.

However, that is *not* what I recommend. Instead, you'll probably find it easier to use a map of maps: `unordered_map<int, unordered_multimap<int, int>>`.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590656/error-for-hash-function-of-pair-of-ints) suggests against declaring the hash in the std namespace.

Comment: @IanPudney: Another question, what does my code compile when I use unordered_map<int, unordered_multimap<int, int>> but not unordered_map<unordered_multimap<int, int>, int>? I get the same as in my original question when inserting into the latter?

Comment: Because in the second case, you're trying to use an `unordered_multimap` as the *key* of your `unordered_map`. Same issue as before: the STL has no idea how to hash an `unordered_multimap`, so if you really want that, you'll have to tell it.

You probably don't really want that.